# error in finding out the lexems and no of lines of a text file in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<ctype.h>

#include<string.h> 


int main()

{

    int i=0,j,k,lines_count[2]={1,1},operand_count[2]={0},operator_count[2]={0},uoperator_count[2]={0},control_count[2]={0,0},cl[13]={0},variable_dec[2]={0,0},l,p[2]={0},ct,variable_used[2]={0,0},constant_count[2],s[2]={0},t[2]={0};

    char a,b[100],c[100];

  char d[100]={0};

    j=30; 



    FILE *fp1[2],*fp2; 


    fp1[0]=fopen("program1.txt","r");

    fp1[1]=fopen("program2.txt","r"); //the source file is opened in read only mode which will passed through the lexer

    fp2=fopen("ccv1ouput.txt","wb");

    //now lets remove all the white spaces and store the rest of the words in a file 


    if(fp1[0]==NULL)

    {

        perror("failed to open program1.txt");

        //return EXIT_FAILURE;

    }

      if(fp1[1]==NULL)

    {

        perror("failed to open program2.txt");

        //return EXIT_FAILURE;

    }

    i=0;

    k=0;

    ct=0;

while(ct!=2)

{

    while(!feof(fp1[ct]))

    { 


        a=fgetc(fp1[ct]); 


        if(a!=' '&&a!='\n')

        {   

                        if (!isalpha(a) && !isdigit(a))

                              { 

                              switch(a)

                                    { 

                                    case '+':{

                                                i=0;

                                                cl[0]=1;

                                                operator_count[ct]=operator_count[ct]+1;break;}

                                    case '-':{ cl[1]=1;

                                                operator_count[ct]=operator_count[ct]+1;i=0;break;}

                                    case '*':{ cl[2]=1;

                                                operator_count[ct]=operator_count[ct]+1;i=0;break;}

                                    case '/':{ cl[3]=1;

                                                operator_count[ct]=operator_count[ct]+1;i=0;break;} 

                                    case '=':{a=fgetc(fp1[ct]);

                                                if (a=='='){cl[4]=1;

                                                      operator_count[ct]=operator_count[ct]+1;

                                                      operand_count[ct]=operand_count[ct]+1;}

                                                else

                                                      { cl[5]=1;

                                                            operator_count[ct]=operator_count[ct]+1;

                                                            operand_count[ct]=operand_count[ct]+1;

                                                            ungetc(1,fp1[ct]);

                                                      }

                                                break;}

                                    case '%':{ cl[6]=1;

                                                operator_count[ct]=operator_count[ct]+1;i=0;break;}

                                    case '<':{ 

                                                a=fgetc(fp1[ct]);

                                                if (a=='=')

                                                      {cl[7]=1;

                                                      operator_count[ct]=operator_count[ct]+1;}

                                                else

                                                      { cl[8]=1;

                                                            operator_count[ct]=operator_count[ct]+1;

                                                            ungetc(1,fp1[ct]);

                                                      }

                                                break;

                                           } 


                                    case '>':{ ;

                                                a=fgetc(fp1[ct]);

                                                if (a=='='){cl[9]=1;

                                                      operator_count[ct]=operator_count[ct]+1;}

                                                else

                                                      { cl[10]=1;

                                                            operator_count[ct]=operator_count[ct]+1;

                                                            ungetc(1,fp1[ct]);

                                                      }

                                                break;} 

                                    case '&':{ cl[11]=1;

                                                a=fgetc(fp1[ct]);

                                                operator_count[ct]=operator_count[ct]+1;

                                                operand_count[ct]=operand_count[ct]+1;

                                                variable_used[ct]=variable_used[ct]-1;

                                                break;

                                          }

                                    case '|':{ cl[12]=1;

                                                a=fgetc(fp1[ct]);

                                                operator_count[ct]=operator_count[ct]+1;

                                                operand_count[ct]=operand_count[ct]+1;

                                                variable_used[ct]=variable_used[ct]-1;

                                                break;

                                          }

                                    case '#':{ while(a!='\n')

                                                {

                                                      a=fgetc(fp1[ct]);

                                                } 

                                          } 




                                    }

                        }

                  else

                        {  

                              d[i]=a;

                              i=i+1;

                              k=k+1;

                        } 







        }

        else

         {

                  //printf("%s \n",d); 

                  if((strcmp(d,"if")==0)){

                                    memset ( d, 0, 100 );

                                    i=0;

                                    control_count[ct]=control_count[ct]+1;

                                    } 

       else if(strcmp(d,"then")==0){

                                    i=0;memset ( d, 0, 100 );control_count[ct]=control_count[ct]+1;} 

       else if(strcmp(d,"else")==0){

                                          i=0;memset ( d, 0, 100 );control_count[ct]=control_count[ct]+1;} 



       else if(strcmp(d,"while")==0){

                                          i=0;memset ( d, 0, 100 );control_count[ct]=control_count[ct]+1;} 


       else if(strcmp(d,"int")==0){ 

                                          while(a != '\n')

                                                { 

                                                      a=fgetc(fp1[ct]);

                                                       if (isalpha(a) )

                                                            variable_dec[ct]=variable_dec[ct]+1; 

                                                } 

                                                memset ( d, 0, 100 );

                                                lines_count[ct]=lines_count[ct]+1; 

                                          } 




       else if(strcmp(d,"char")==0){while(a != '\n')

                                                { a=fgetc(fp1[ct]);

                                                       if (isalpha(a) )

                                                            variable_dec[ct]=variable_dec[ct]+1; 

                                                } 

                                                memset ( d, 0, 100 );

                                                lines_count[ct]=lines_count[ct]+1;

                                                }

       else if(strcmp(d,"float")==0){while(a != '\n')

                                                { a=fgetc(fp1[ct]);

                                                       if (isalpha(a) )

                                                            variable_dec[ct]=variable_dec[ct]+1; 

                                                } 

                                                memset ( d, 0, 100 );

                                                lines_count[ct]=lines_count[ct]+1; 

                                                }

       else if(strcmp(d,"printf")==0){while(a!='\n')

                                                a=fgetc(fp1[ct]);

                                          memset(d,0,100);

                                          }

       else if(strcmp(d,"scanf")==0){while(a!='\n')

                                          a=fgetc(fp1[ct]);

                                          memset(d,0,100);}



            else  if (isdigit(d[i-1]))

                  {  

                        memset ( d, 0, 100 );

                        i=0;

                        constant_count[ct]=constant_count[ct]+1;

                        operand_count[ct]=operand_count[ct]+1; 

                  }

            else if (isalpha(d[i-1]) && strcmp(d,"int")!=0 && strcmp(d,"char")!=0  && strcmp(d,"float")!=0 && (strcmp(d,"if")!=0) && strcmp(d,"then")!=0 && strcmp(d,"else")!=0 && strcmp(d,"while")!=0 && strcmp(d,"printf")!=0 && strcmp(d,"scanf")!=0)

                  {  

                        memset ( d, 0, 100 );

                        i=0; 

                        operand_count[ct]=operand_count[ct]+1;



                  }

             else if(a=='\n')

            {

            lines_count[ct]=lines_count[ct]+1;

            memset ( d, 0, 100 );

            } 



         } 




    } 

fclose(fp1[ct]);

operand_count[ct]=operand_count[ct]-5;

variable_used[0]=operand_count[0]-constant_count[0];

variable_used[1]=operand_count[1]-constant_count[1];

for(j=0;j<12;j++)

uoperator_count[ct]=uoperator_count[ct]+cl[j];

fprintf(fp2,"\n statistics of program %d",ct+1);

fprintf(fp2,"\n the no of lines ---> %d",lines_count[ct]);

fprintf(fp2,"\n the no of operands --->%d",operand_count[ct]);

fprintf(fp2,"\n the no of operator --->%d",operator_count[ct]);

fprintf(fp2,"\n the no of control statments --->%d",control_count[ct]);

fprintf(fp2,"\n the no of unique operators --->%d",uoperator_count[ct]);

fprintf(fp2,"\n the no of variables declared--->%d",variable_dec[ct]);

fprintf(fp2,"\n the no of variables used--->%d",variable_used[ct]);

fprintf(fp2,"\n ---------------------------------");

fprintf(fp2,"\n \t \t \t"); 

ct=ct+1; 

} 


t[0]=lines_count[0]+control_count[0]+uoperator_count[0];

t[1]=lines_count[1]+control_count[1]+uoperator_count[1]; 



s[0]=operator_count[0]+operand_count[0]+variable_dec[0]+variable_used[0];

s[1]=operator_count[1]+operand_count[1]+variable_dec[1]+variable_used[1]; 

fprintf(fp2,"\n the time complexity of program 1 is %d",t[0]);

fprintf(fp2,"\n the time complexity of program 2 is %d",t[1]);

fprintf(fp2,"\n the space complexity of program 1 is %d",s[0]);

fprintf(fp2,"\n the space complexity of program 2 is %d",s[1]);

if((t[0]>t[1]) && (s[0] >s[1]))

fprintf(fp2,"\n the efficiency of program 2 is greater than program 1");

else if(t[0]<t[1] && s[0] < s[1])

fprintf(fp2,"\n the efficiency of program 1 is greater than program 2 " );

else if (t[0]+s[0] > t[1]+s[1])

fprintf(fp2,"\n the efficiency of program 1 is greater than program 2");

else if (t[0]+s[0] < t[1]+s[1])

fprintf(fp2,"\n the efficiency of program 2 is greater than program 1");

else if (t[0]+s[0] == t[1]+s[1])

fprintf(fp2,"\n the efficiency of program 1 is equal to that of program 2"); 



fclose(fp2); 


return 0;

}
```

this code basically compares two c codes and finds out the no. of variables declared , used , no. of control statements , no. of lines and no. of unique operators , and operands , so as to find out the time complexity and space complexity of of the two programs given in the text file program1.txt and program2.txt ...

Lets say program1.txt is this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main ()
{
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("output.txt","w");
long double  t,y=0,x=0,e=5,f=1,w=1;
for (t=0;t<10;t=t+0.01)
{
//if (isnan(y) || isinf(y)) 
//break;
fprintf(fp,"%ld\t%ld\n",y,x);

y = y + ((e*(1 - (x*x))*y) - x + f*cos(w*0.1))*0.1;
x = x + y*0.1;
}
fclose(fp);
return (0);
}
```

i havent indented it as its just a text file . But my output is totally faulty . Its not able to find the any of the ouput that i need . Where is the bug in this ? I am not able to figure out as the algorithm looks fine .

Comment: Fixing the formatting of the source code (indentation and double line spacing) would probably help.

Comment: not homework. just a learning curve ..

Comment: ok atleast tell me why my no of lines are not coming rt?

Comment: I'm not even ging to *try* to read the code in its present state - the bad formatting makes it too much like hard work - if you can't be bothered to format code sensibly then you can't really expect people to take the extra time and effort to debug it for you.

Comment: ok sorry for the identation .. was a bit hasty ..

Comment: It would help us to understand (and perhaps allow you to debug yourself) id the code was simpler - perhaps just try to get a working version to find the number lines first. When that works then start adding counters for other data

Comment: can you please look into the bug while finding the no of lines and nothing else ..

Comment: Not really - you should do the work and cut the code down just to do that. We are not here to do your work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a function that is given a `FILE *` (and perhaps the file name too), and reads and analyzes that file.  You might create a structure to store the statistics in;  you might pass that into the function, or you might have the function return it.  You might create some extra functions to read parts of the file - reading quoted strings, comments, and single quoted characters are all possible candidates.

Your main program would then call the analysis function twice, once for each file, collecting the statistics structures, which you can then print in a comparative format (probably another function).

In the code, you have:

```
int i=0,j,k,lines_count[2]={1,1},operand_count[2]={0},operator_count[2]={0},uoperator_count[2]={0},control_count[2]={0,0},cl[13]={0},variable_dec[2]={0,0},l,p[2]={0},ct,variable_used[2]={0,0},constant_count[2],s[2]={0},t[2]={0};
```

This should be split over multiple lines for readability.  Indeed, I'd repeat the keyword `int` and have each variable separate:

```
int i=0;
int j;
int k;
int lines_count[2]={1,1};
int operand_count[2]={0};
int operator_count[2]={0};
int uoperator_count[2]={0};
int control_count[2]={0,0};
int cl[13]={0};
int variable_dec[2]={0,0};
int l;
int p[2]={0};
int ct;
int variable_used[2]={0,0};
int constant_count[2];
int s[2]={0};
int t[2]={0};
```

We can now see that you have inconsistent initializers for your arrays.  The result is the same (the missing values are treated as zeroes anyway).  It is odd that your files have one line in them before anything is read.  It is also worth not having a blank line between every statement.  It makes it very hard to read the code.  The majority of the two-element arrays would become parts of the statistics structure in my design.